# How to manage a list of dropdowns with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an application where the user is presented with a list of dropdowns. Each dropdown has the same list of options. The user can add a new dropdown or remove one. See screenshot below.

[image]

I want to maintain what the user has selected as a simple list of values selected. For Example, for the above screenshot, I want to have the selection stored in the `$scope` somewhere as

```
["homepage", "keyword", "location", "original_priority"]
```

Is this possible with AngularJS i.e. the user removes and adds dropdowns and angular automatically updates the list of selected values?

**What I have tried so far**

```
 var ClassifierController = function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.selected_classifiers = ['homepage', 'keyword', 'location', 'original_priority'];

    /* Calling a service to get a list of values for the dropdowns */
    $http.get('/rest/classifiers').then(function(resp) {
      $scope.classifiers = resp.data;
    });

    $scope.add = function() {
      console.log("Add");
      // Checking if none is already in the list
      var index = $scope.selected_classifiers.indexOf("none");
      if (index > -1) {
        alert("Cannot add. An unspecified grouper is already available at index " + (index+1));
      }
      else {
        $scope.selected_classifiers.push("none");
      }
    }

    $scope.remove = function(selection) {
      console.log("Remove " + selection);
      var index = $scope.selected_classifiers.indexOf(selection);
      if (index > -1) {
        $scope.selected_classifiers.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
 }
```

Then in the html

```
 <div ng-controller="ClassifierController">
   <ol>
     <li ng-repeat="selection in selected_classifiers">
       <select>{{selection}}>
         <option ng-repeat="classifier in classifiers" value="{{classifier.value}}" ng-selected="classifier.value==selection">{{classifier.name}}</option>
       </select> <button title="Remove" ng-click="remove(selection)">X</ux-button>
     </li>
    <li><button title="Add new grouper" ng-click="add()">Add</ux-button></li>
   </ol>
 </div>
```

The setup above works to present a good initial setup. There removes work, but the update of an existing dropdown OR update of a newly added dropdown does not work.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's very possible and there are many ways to do it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've added when I've tried till now.

Comment: I'm confused about `selected_classifiers` and `classifiers`. Are these type of drop downs or the values of `<options>`? Can you give an example? And what does "Add" do?

Comment: `classifiers` is a fixed list of classifiers that are available. They form the basis of the options in all the dropdowns. `selected_classifiers` is an ordered list of selected classifiers as the user sees on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with anything Angular, first define what your ViewModel looks like.

For example, if you want to have a list of `select` names and their values, define the list to be like so:

```
$scope.selected_classifiers = [{name: "homepage", val: ""}, ...];
```

`selected_classifiers` will hold/initialize the values of each selection, and also keep what selections you actually have.

Then, in the View, iterate over this list and create `<selects>`:

```
<div ng-repeat="selection in selected_classifiers">
    <select ng-model="selection.val"
            ng-options="classifier for classifier in classifiers">
       <option value="">{{selection.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <button title="Remove" ng-click="remove(selection)">X</button>
</div>
<button title="Add new grouper" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TjTVlNNnDgGygATEUAld)

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked very well! The bit I was missing was to connect each `<select>` to a model.